# How to test Google App Engine locally with real Google account?

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, oauth

Is it possible to locally test an App Engine application with a real Google login, rather than test@example.com?

I'm trying to save the trouble of deploying to test out OAuth authentication, which I'm hoping is possible.

Thanks very much,
Charlie

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot use your real one, but instead of `test@example.com` you can use whatever you want, to test it with multiple different accounts. The only difference when you're going to deploy it is that it will redirect you to Google login, instead of this blue login screen. It doesn't ask for password because it's a dev environment, and you should be able to test it with multiple accounts without the actual need of an account. Deploy it once to test it and then assume that it works.